# Ignore properties(Hashtable) value with null

Tags: java, properties, hashtable

I have a method which accept `java.util.Properties` parameter,

I need to put various parameters, that can its value can be null.

I'm getting `NullPointerException` because of [Hashtable.put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put(K,%20V)) can't receive null value

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:460)
        ...
```

I can fix it by using method that check nulls:

```
private void putIfNotNull(Properties p, String name, String value) {
    if (value!= null) {
        p.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Or create a wrapper class and use it:

```
public class PropertyHolder extends Properties {
    @Override
    public Object put( Object key, Object value ) {
        if (value != null) {
            return super.put(key, value);           
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and use it similar as Property:

```
Properties p = new PropertyHolder();
```

Is the second option is the right one? or is there a simpler/built in solution?

Comment: Is the second option the right one? No. Extending collections is almost always a bad idea. And there are several other ways to add values to a map, that would bypass your check. But most importantly, you should almost never ignore an invalid method call and pretend it is valid: putting a null value is a bug, that should be signalled by throwing a NullPointerException, and fixed.

Comment: @JBNizet But not all map implementation throws NullPointerException, so allow sending null values isn't a bug always, I just want to ignore such values, while using `Properties`

Comment: Well, if you chose to use Properties, knowing that it can't hold null values, and you still try putting null values in it, then it's clearly a bug, or a bad design choice to use Properties. So you should not accept a null value and ignore it silently, because it indicates a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the PropertyHolder override! It easily helped me with a copy/paste of it. (FYI your example above is missing a final closed curly bracket to complete the class if you wanted to update it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `putIfNotNull` method is a better option because it makes it explicitly clear that it will not put the value if it is null. Creating a subclass of `Properties` that silently rejects null values inside the `put` method means breaking the expected behaviour of Maps - if `put("key", value)` returns without throwing an exception, then get("key") should return that same `value`.

Comment: Can you elaborate why/if there's another option?

Comment: @user7294900 Java's standard library classes have well defined behaviour. The `Map.put` method for example, must either associate the given key with the given value, or fail with an exception. And if `Map.put(key, value)` is successful, `Map.containsKey(key)` and Map.containsValue(`value`) should return true, and `Map.get(key)` should return `value`. 

It is bad practice to override these methods in a way that breaks their specified behaviour, so your second option is not advisable. And to answer your other question, no there is no built in solution, and the first option is the easiest.